# xmpp ping receiving blackberry java

Tags: blackberry, java-me, xmpp

I don't know where I am doing wrong when I get ping iq from xmpp i am getting exception bad ioe exception.Please help me as there is no consistent connection with xmpp.

Here is the code where I am reading the ping iq and sending ping to xmpp serve

```
if(type.equals("get"))

{

while (true) {

            if((reader.getType() == XmlReader.END_TAG) && reader.getName().equals("iq"))
            {

                this.xmppThread.pingResult(from,id);
        pingCheck=true;



        }
        }
}
```

The code for sending iq to xmpp:

```
public void pingResult(String to,String id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String msg = "<iq type=result to="+to+"id="+id+"/>";

    try {
        os.write(msg.getBytes());
        os.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```